# How to install latest version of Cheese from source in Raring?

Tags: compiling, install-from-source, cheese

The source files can be downloaded from here. I want to use the last stable version.

1. How to install Cheese from source?
2. Or Is there any .deb file of version 3.8.3 available somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Download the latest version for Raring from [here](http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cheese/cheese_3.8.2-0ubuntu1~raring1_i386.deb)**

**Installing..**

- Go to Downloads or directory where you downloaded .deb file

  ```
  cd ~/Downloads
  ```
- Install by executing:

  ```
  sudo dpkg -i cheese_3.8.2-0ubuntu1~raring1_i386.deb
  ```

Be sure that you have installed the dependent packages of **Cheese**. If you run:

```
    $ sudo dpkg -i cheese_3.8.2-0ubuntu1~raring1_i386.deb
```

It will give errory message some what like:

```
Selecting previously unselected package cheese.
(Reading database ... 227378 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking cheese (from cheese_3.8.2-0ubuntu1~raring1_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cheese:
 cheese depends on libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0); however:
  Package libcheese-gtk23 is not installed.
 cheese depends on libcheese7 (>= 3.5.1); however:
  Package libcheese7 is not installed.
 cheese depends on libclutter-1.0-0 (>= 1.13.0); however:
  Version of libclutter-1.0-0 on system is 1.10.6-1~precise1.
 cheese depends on libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 (>= 1.4.0); however:
  Version of libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 on system is 1.2.0-0ubuntu1.
 cheese depends on libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.35.9); however:
  Version of libglib2.0-0 on system is 2.32.3-0ubuntu1.
 cheese depends on libgnome-desktop-3-7 (>= 3.2.0); however:
  Package libgnome-desktop-3-7 is not installed.
 cheese depends on libgstreamer1.0-0 (>= 1.0.0); however:
  Package libgstreamer1.0-0 is not installed.
 cheese depends on libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.6); however:
  Version of libgtk-3-0 on system is 3.4.2-0ubuntu0.5.
 cheese depends on cheese-common (>= 3.4); however:
  Package cheese-common is not installed.
 cheese depends on gnome-video-effects; however:
  Package gnome-video-effects is not installed.
dpkg: error processing cheese (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 cheese
```

And thus installs a broken package. So fix this broken package by executing:

```
    $ sudo apt-get -f install
    $ sudo apt-get update
    $ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

`apt-get upgrade` is necessary because it insures that you have latest library files.

**Then how to install with dependent packages** (here you are:)

- Latest version of **Cheese** requires following packages:

`cheese-common` `gir1.2-cheese-3.0` `libcheese-dev` `libcheese-doc` `libcheese-gtk-dev`
`libcheese-gtk23` and `libcheese7`

- Download it [from here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/gnome_3/raring/main/base/cheese) one by one and put in the same directory where **cheese_3.8.2-0ubuntu1~raring1_i386.deb** is saved.
- Then go to directory **cheese** and execute this command (*I am assuming that you placed all .deb file in a directory cheese* somewhere in your system.):

  ```
  $ sudo dpkg -i *.deb
  ```

Reply for further assistance.. Hope it will work now.

Comment: be sure that you have all dependent packages installed. You can use  `Synaptic Package Manager` to install dependent packages.

Comment: I did so and Cheese became a broken package

Comment: That is why I suggested to install the dependent packages first.. Select the missing packages from `down to up` while installing cheese. Search for those packages in `Synaptic Package Manager` one by one and try to install it. You can also use `terminal` to install it: `sudo apt-get -f install <package1> <package2> <..>` Hope it works for you..

Comment: How would I know what are the dependencies? The control file?

Comment: Ok.. Wait I'm editing my answer and replying it as a full answer.. I hope you would be able to understand. I appreciate your patience. Thanks..

Comment: It says unable to locate package 'libgnome-desktop-3-7'